# how to save input from text field with form in ruby on rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I need to save input taken from the user, but I found a code that works in a bad and old format,

File: public\input.html, adding this code:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Using Text Fields</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Working With Text Fields</h1>
    This Ruby on Rails application lets you read data from text fields.
    <br>
    <form action = "/hello/there" >
      Please enter your name.
      <br>
      <input type="text" name="text1">
      <br>
      <br>
      <input type="submit"/>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

File: app\controllers\hello_controller.rb:

```
class HelloController < ApplicationController
  def there
    @data = params[:text1]
  end
end
```

File: app\views\hello\there.rhtml:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Reading data from text fields</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Reading data from text fields</h1>
    This Ruby on Rails application reads data from text fields.
    <br>
    <br>
    Your name is <%= @data %>.
    <br>
    <br>
  </body>
</html>

Start the WEBrick server: ruby script/server
Navigate to http://localhost:3000/input.html
```

That is the code snippet, to be honest it works like a charm, but in the current rails api it gives me something like this:

```
<!--
<form action = "home/omg" >

  <%= label_tag(:text1, "Enter the message:") %>
  <%= text_field_tag :text1 %>
  <%= submit_tag"submit" %>
-->
```

So whats the difference and how can i use the given input,

What I want and need is when user clicks the button - submit button - take the text in the text field and use it as a string in my home controller. How can i accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

The only difference is that the code you found in the Rails guides uses [Rails form helpers](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html).  The form helpers will be evaluated on the server, and the result will be sent to the client almost exactly the same as it is in your first example.  Try using the form helpers and then navigate to your application in a browser.  Right click to "Inspect Element" and you'll see standard markup, similar to what you have written.

As for using the given input, is something currently not working?  I haven't tested your code but it looks like it should work.  If the string is not showing up in `there.rhtml`, could explain what is happening?

Answer (score 0):

Like an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25273551/1183537) suggested, view the Rails guide to see how [Rails form helper](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html) `form_tag` works.

In your `app/views/hello/edit.erb.html` or where you have your form (won't work in `public/*.html` because those are static resources). Use the `form_tag` in the [ERB](http://www.stuartellis.eu/articles/erb/) (Embedded RuBy file that outputs HTML) like:

```rb
<%= form_tag("/hello/there") do %>
  <%= label_tag(:text1, "Please enter your name") %>
  <%= text_field_tag :text1 %>
  <%= submit_tag %>
<% end %>
```

will output HTML:

```html
<form action="/hello/there">
  <label for="text1">Please enter your name</label>
  <input type="text" name="text1" id="text1" />
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: I noticed the example uses `.rhtml` instead of ERB `.erb.html` which is similar but outdated and won't work in Rails 3+, I'm pretty sure.